# Create a function toGradePoints() that takes an array of letter grades as input and returns a corresponding array of grade points

Tags: javascript

```js
    
function toGradePoints(letter) {
  //var score = '';
  var grade = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) 
  {
    //result = '';
    if (letter[i] = "A") {
      grade[i] = 4.0;
    } else if (letter[i] = "A-") {
      grade[i] = 3.7;
    } else if (letter[i] = "B+") {
      grade[i] = 3.3;
    } else if (letter[i] = "B") {
      grade[i] = 3.0;
    } else if (letter[i] = "B-") {
      grade[i] = 2.7 ;
    } else if (letter[i] = "C+") {
      grade[i] = 2.4;
    } else if (score[i] = "C") {
      grade[i] = 2.0;
    } else if (score[i] = "C-") {
      grade[i] = 1.7;
    } else {
      grade[i] = 0;
    }
   // result.push(score);
  }
 return grade;
     
}
  
  var y=[]
  y=["B","B+","C-","D"];

  var m=toGradePoints(y);

console.log(m)
```

[Here is the link, q1.2](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/receptive-xylophone?path=index.html:108:46)

It only displays 4 all the time, I don't know which part went wrong.

Comment: Hi! you have `=` everywhere, but you actually need `==`. One `=` is assign, two `==` are compare.

Comment: Thank you! It's fixed now. I am totally a beginner :)

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning value with `=` instead of comparing with an operator `==` when checking the alphabetic grade.

```
letter[i] = "A"
```

Should be:

```
letter[i] == "A"
```

Also you have a type you refer in a couple of if conditionals to a wrong `score` which should be changed to `letter`.

Full code fixed:

```
function toGradePoints(letter) {
  //var score = '';
  var grade = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) 
  {
    //result = '';
    if (letter[i] == "A") {
      grade[i] = 4.0;
    } else if (letter[i] == "A-") {
      grade[i] = 3.7;
    } else if (letter[i] == "B+") {
      grade[i] = 3.3;
    } else if (letter[i] == "B") {
      grade[i] = 3.0;
    } else if (letter[i] == "B-") {
      grade[i] = 2.7 ;
    } else if (letter[i] == "C+") {
      grade[i] = 2.4;
    } else if (letter[i] == "C") {
      grade[i] = 2.0;
    } else if (letter[i] == "C-") {
      grade[i] = 1.7;
    } else {
      grade[i] = 0;
    }
   // result.push(score);
  }
 return grade;

}

  var y=[]
  y=["B","B+","C-","D"];

  var m=toGradePoints(y);

console.log(m)
```